# New Coverity user, scan failing with "last build status: failed"

Tags: coverity, sast, coverity-prevent

I am trying to use the free version of coverity scan on a python repo, but it returns the error:
"Last Build Status: Failed - No further action needed.. Your build will be added back to the queue for analysis".

I have created a project in Coverity for an example python repo and then executed these commands to generate a tar to upload. I found these commands on Coverity's page https://scan.coverity.com/download?tab=other

`cov-configure --python`

`cov-build --dir cov-int --no-command --fs-capture-search ./`

`tar czvf myproject.tgz cov-int`

Then when I submit this tar to the coverity scan page it gives me the error "Last Build Status: Failed - No further action needed.. Your build will be added back to the queue for analysis." and it never completes. Could it be the repo I am using: https://github.com/EMChamp/DVPFWA-1

I've tried 4 more repos from different languages and it doesn't work. I was expecting results of vulnerabilities from the scan.

When I check cov-int/build-log.txt it says

> 353 Python compilation units (100%) are ready for analysis
> The cov-build utility completed successfully.